# Converting table data into nested JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm new to C# (coming from a JavaScript background) and it seems like this code could be greatly improved.

This SQL query:

```
SELECT RegionString,SubRegionString,CountryString,COUNT(*) AS size
FROM table
GROUP BY RegionString,SubRegionString,CountryString
```

Returns:

> ```
> RegionString SubRegionString CountryString Size
> -----------------------------------------------
> Americas                                  2
> Americas   NorthAmerica    Canada         5
> Americas   NorthAmerica    US             3
> Americas   SouthAmerica    Chile          3
> EMEA       AsiaPacific     Australia      2
> EMEA       AsiaPacific     Japan          1
> EMEA       SouthernEurope  Turkey         1
> EMEA       WesternEurope                  1
> ```

I made this C# code:

```cs
public class NameChildObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public List<NameChildObject> children { get; set; }

    public NameChildObject() 
    {
        children = new List<NameChildObject>();
    }
}

public ActionResult ByRegion()
{
    var returnResults = new List<NameChildObject>();

    var uniqueRegions = (from row in repository.GetAllEntities()
                         select row.RegionString).Distinct();

    foreach (string region in uniqueRegions)
    {
        returnResults.Add(new NameChildObject() { name = region });

        var uniqueSubRegions = (from row in repository.GetAllEntities()
                                where row.RegionString == region
                                select row.SubRegionString).Distinct();

        foreach (string subRegion in uniqueSubRegions)
        {
            var regionObject = returnResults.Find(row => row.name == region);

            var countryInfo = (from row in repository.GetAllEntities()
                               where row.SubRegionString == subRegion
                               group row by row.CountryString into g
                               select new NameChildObject() { name = g.Key, size = g.Count() });

            regionObject.children.Add(new NameChildObject() { name = subRegion, children = countryInfo.ToList()});
        }
    }

    return Json(returnResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

To convert the data into this format:

```cs
[
    {
        "name": "Americas",
        "size": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "size": 2,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "NorthAmerica",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Canada",
                        "size": 5,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "US",
                        "size": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SouthAmerica",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Chile",
                        "size": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "EMEA",
        "size": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "AsiaPacific",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Australia",
                        "size": 2,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Japan",
                        "size": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SouthernEurope",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Turkey",
                        "size": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "WesternEurope",
                "size": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "size": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have three calls to `repository.GetAllEntities()`. If those execute a db call each time, that's a bad thing. But it actually points to a deeper issue.

May I introduce you to [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
foreach(var regionStringGroup in repository.GetAllEntities().GroupBy(x => x.RegionString))
{
    var regionObject = new NameChildObject() { name = region };

    foreach(var subRegionStringGroup in regionStringGroup.GroupBy(x => x.SubRegionString))
    {
        var children = subRegionStringGroup
           .GroupBy(x => x.CountryString)
           .Select(x => new NameChildObject() { name = x.Key, size = x.Count() }).ToList()
        regionObject.children.Add(new NameChildObject() 
           { name = subRegion, children = children});
    }

    returnResults.Add(regionObject);
}
```

I do have to say I'm not 100% sure about how you create `countryInfo` because I lack some knowledge about the data you're processing, so please don't just use my code blindly but compare it to your results.

---

`children`, `name`, `size`: [public properties should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

Is your class actually called `NameChildObject`? Can't say I like that name, especially the "Object" at the end.

Ditto for the property `RegionString` by the way: avoid suffixing a name with its type. Ditto `CountryString`.

`ByRegion()` isn't a good method name. `GetByRegion` doesn't feel right either since the "by region" implies there's a parameter, and there isn't. Perhaps something like `GetRegionTree`?

`Size` isn't really the best name either. Perhaps `ChildCount`? I don't even think it should be part of the query, since <del>you could simply count the items in your various groups</del> you're not using it anyway.

---

Hmm, I just noticed the resulting JSON is quite odd. Why not include the `Size` when you're constructing the `RegionString`-level `NameChildObject`?